# Link UIButton To A Specific Tab Within Several Different Tab Bar Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I have an 'Enter' button on my app index/main page.

This button links to one of two (2) different tab bar controllers - depending on whether the user has purchased full access or not. Each tab bar controller has 3 tabs.

These two (2) tab bar controllers are named "TabBarControllerFree" and "TabBarControllerPaid" respectively.

I have written the following code to determine where the user is 'sent':

```
@IBAction func Enter(sender: AnyObject) {

    //Check if product is purchased
    if (defaults.boolForKey("purchased")){
         print("User has purchased")

        // Send User To Paid TabBarController - FULL Access:

        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarControllerPaid") as! TabBarControllerPaid
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    else if (!defaults.boolForKey("purchased")){
           print("user has NOT purchased")

        // Send User To Free TabBarController - PARTIAL Access:
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarControllerFree") as! TabBarControllerFree
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

At present, the user is sent to the first tab within the respective Tab Bar Controllers by default (index 0 or the left-most tab).

I would like to have the option of sending the user to the second tab (index 1) or third tab (index 2).

I realise I have to effect "SelectedIndex = 1" or "SelectedIndex = 2" into my code.

How can I do this please?

** ADDITIONAL INFO **

This is a snapshot of my storyboard map:

[image]

Basically, I have three (3) buttons (green colour) on my initial VC (the landing page).

(1) If the user clicks 'Enter', I check if they have full access or not, and send them to the respective Paid or Free Tab Bar Controller (red arrows).

(2) If the user clicks 'Workouts' I send them to the same Tab Bar Controllers in the same manner as the first/left most (index 0) tabs on both are 'Workouts' (yellow arrows).

(3) If the user clicks 'Exercises' I would like to send them to the second left most tab (index 1) in respective Paid or Free Tab Bar Controllers (blue arrows).

It is button three (3) for 'Exercises' that I am struggling to execute effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work, you have to change some settings in Xcode. Select the target. Go to the General tab. Where it says Main Interface, make it blank.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    // Add this
    var mainViewController: UITabBarController?
    var isPaid: Bool {
        get {
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            let saveIt = defaults.objectForKey("isPaid") as? Bool ?? false
            return saveIt
        }
        set(newBool) {
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setObject(newBool, forKey: "isPaid")
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        if isPaid {
            mainViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabControllerPaid") as? UITabBarController
        }
        else {
            mainViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabControllerFree") as? UITabBarController
        }

        mainViewController?.selectedIndex = 0
        self.window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    }
    // .......
}
```

Comment: Not able to. This error appears : `Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'`. In my code I think I have to declare a variable as a `UITabBarController' to adopt the property?

Comment: My bad. Please note edited answer. I have used this in one of my apps.

Comment: I have tried the code, it just sends me to the VC at index 0 (I think by default?). This is my code: `let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarControllerFree") as! TabBarControllerFree` ... next line ...
`self.presentViewController(vc.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: I have tried to link directly to the particular VC at the index I want as destination with this code: `let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WorkoutsAllFreeVC") as! WorkoutsAllFreeVC` ... next line ...
`self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`. This send the user to the required destination VC, but I lose the tab bar at the bottom.

Comment: Is this TabBar supposed to be the root controller?

Comment: I have added a storyboard map and some notes in my amended question to provide more detail. Apologies, I should have included some graphical reference initially :-)

Comment: @ ryantxr Yes, I believe the target TabBar is a root controller. As I have 4 Navigation Controllers and 4 root controllers. Each is a 'target' for a respective link.

Comment: Tell me if this concept would work for you. In AppDelegate, determine if you are in free or paid mode, then instantiate the correct tabbar controller there and launch to it.

Comment: I guess so. I am very new and 'green', apologies but I don't know how I would do that. At the moment, in my main InitialVC I have this code `let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` ... next line ...  `var product_id: NSString?;` and then I make reference to my product  ID in the `ViewDidLoad` section.

Comment: Brilliant! I get the logic, will take me a little time to customise it re my targets, etc.. but super duper! Terima Kasih! Very much appreciated!